# How do I select part of a BLOB field in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table in Oracle that stores files as byte arrays in a BLOB field.  I want my client to be able to download the stored file in small chunks (as opposed to downloading the whole thing all at once) so I can display a progress bar.

How can I write an Oracle query that retrieves only *part* of the contents of a BLOB field?  I imagine it would be something like this:

```
SELECT PARTOF(BLOBFIELD, 1000, 2000) AS CHUNK FROM tbl WHERE ID = 1
```

if I wanted to get 1000 bytes from BLOBFIELD starting at byte 2000.

As a secondary question, are there any performance issues with this?  If Oracle has to load the entire BLOB field into memory in order to return part of it, then this wouldn't be a very good idea.

Comment: i would suggest trying to solve this issue in another way first. What language/framework etc. are you using to talk to your Oracle db? i'm thinking that you could more simply achieve a progress bar report outside of Oracle's capabilities.

Comment: My clients are Windows Mobile devices calling an ASP.NET web service. For the progress bar to work, the clients need to be able to make multiple calls to the web service, each of which returns a piece of the overall file. In order to do this, I have to be able to write a query that returns just a piece of a BLOB field.

Comment: Had you stored the file in the filesystem you'd have no such problem.

Comment: "Had you stored the file in the filesystem you'd have no such problem."  True, you'd have different (worse?) problems!

Comment: "True, you'd have different (worse?) problems!" True, although worse is on the eye of the problem's beholder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use [DBMS_LOB.READ (lob_loc, amount, offset, buffer)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999170)?

Comment: `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` is what I actually need, but I found it in your link, so you get the check. Thanks.